# ASP.NET WebAPI: Inconsistent IPrincipal within a request execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET WebAPI with a bearer token based authentication. `System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter` is used to validate user tokens.

This is my security settings inside `WebApiConfig` (`config` is an instance of `HttpConfiguration`):

```
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

I observed quite a strange behavior related to reading of `IPrincipal` inside `ApiController.ExecuteAsync` method when executing an authenticated request: I have a custom base-controller class that derives from `ApiController` and overrides `ExecuteAsync` method.

```
public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Here:
    // HttpContext.Curent.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false
    // Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false
    //
    // (this is expected behavior - request gets authenticated inside 
    // a base.ExecuteAsync call)

    HttpResponseMessage result = await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);

    // However here:
    // HttpContext.Curent.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true
    // Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false

    return result;
}
```

Why is `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false` while `HttpContext.Curent.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true` after a `base.ExecuteAsync()` call? Is this an expected behavior?

Is there a way how to ensure that both `HttpContext.Curent.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` are `true` after `ExecuteAsync` (when a request is properly authenticated)?

(Inside of controller methods eg. `GetAsync`, `PostAsync`, both `HttpContext.Curent.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` are `true`.)

Comment: Read this article it might help http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

Comment: This is because authentication doesn't happen until the request comes into the application, it happens very early before anything else, so that all the redirect stuff happens under the cover.  Once the request is sent across the wire the Identity.IsAuthenticated should happen but only if everything is done correctly.